# Slim 3 Framework - hospedado em subdiretório roteia incorretamente

Tags: php, api, slim

Tenho uma api hospedada na máquina local de desenvolvimento no seguinte diretório:

```
root/www/api/v2
```

Se eu acessar servindo pelo apache, minhas rotas não são reconhecidas, nem mesmo se acessar por http://localhost/api/v2/rota e nem por http://localhost/api/v2/index.php/rota

Se eu acessar servindo direto pelo **php -S 0.0.0.0** (buit-in server) funciona, contudo, outro problema ocorre, rewrite mode do apache .htaccess não funciona, se eu tentar passara uma parâmetro com o carácter . (ponto) ele se perde, um exemplo seria passar um e-mail ou domínio no parâmetro.

Infelizmente meu ambiente de desenvolvimento na empresa é windows, já até pesquisei que seja provável um problema até com o OS. Alguém já passou por algo parecido ou tem alguma solução razoável?

Comment: Não acredito no problema em SO, porque, eu tenho aplicação rodando Slim com Windows e funciona as rotas naturamente, claro configuradas no meu servidor. Isso está com cara de Configuração. Pergunto você roda o seu servidor na raiz pasta da aplicação slim ?

Comment: A api está em root/www/api/v2/public. Estou usando slim 3 com a última versão do XAMP e a última do WAMP também. Em slim 2 funciona normalmente.

Comment: Você criou o .htaccess como descrito nesse link: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html

Comment: Sim, inclusive já tentei muitas outras maneiras.

Comment: O problema é engraçado porque acabei de instalar o slim3 e funciona com o meu servidor e com o comando php -S localhost:85 perfeitamente ... !!! não sei bem o que poderia ser

Comment: Então tente php -S localhost:85 com a seguinte rota: http://localhost:85/teste/exemplo@dominio.com - Claro que você deve criar a rota teste com um parâmetro $app->get('/teste/:email', function ($email) { echo $email; });

Comment: Eu criei a rota, eu fiz exemplos de rotas e testei, funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Crie um rota normal e um diretório exclusivo e configure esses servidores seu que vai rodar!